# How to define a JSON schema where an array of objects contains at least the elements with the expected names

Tags: json, jsonschema

I would like to define a JSON schema (draft 04) where an array of objects (here `files`) contains *at least* the elements with the defined `name`s (here `a`, `b`, `c`).

1. This should **pass**:

```
"files": [
  { "name": "a" },
  { "name": "b" },
  { "name": "c" }
]
```

2. This should **fail** (element with name `c` is missing):

```
"files": [
  { "name": "a" },
  { "name": "b" }
]
```

3. This should **fail** (element with name `c` is missing):

```
"files": [
  { "name": "a" },
  { "name": "b" },
  { "name": "a" }
]
```

4. This should **pass**:

```
"files": [
  { "name": "a" },
  { "name": "b" },
  { "name": "c" },
  { "name": "d" }
]
```

`minItems`, `uniqueItems` and `enum` allow me to cover case 1, 2 and 3, but it does not cover case 4, since it does not allow name `d`:

```
"files": {
  "minItems": 3,
  "uniqueItems": true,
  "items": {
    "properties": {
      "name": {
        "enum": ["a", "b", "c"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Any ideas to write validation to require at least the elements with names `a`, `b` and `c`, while also allowing additional items with other names in JSON schema draft 04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first look at it using some draft-06 or higher keywords because it's easier to understand. Then we'll translate it to draft-04.

We can use the `contains` keyword to assert that an array contains at least one item that matches a schema. This example shows asserting that an array must contain an object with a property "name" whose value is `"a"`.

```json
{
  "contains": {
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "name": { "const": "a" }
    },
    "required": ["name"]
  }
}
```

You can combine multiple assertions like this these using `allOf` to assert for "b" and "c" as well.

```json
{
  "allOf": [
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/contains-a" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/contains-b" },
    { "$ref": "#/definitions/contains-c" }
  ]
}
```

Now we need to translate to draft-04. `const` is easy.

```json
{ "const": "a" }
```

becomes

```json
{ "enum": ["a"] }
```

The transformation for `contains` is far less intuitive, but it works. I suggest putting them in `definitions` (like shown in the `allOf` example) to make your schema more readable.

```json
{ "contains": { "$ref": "#/definitions/name-a" } }
```

becomes

```json
{
  "not": {
    "items": {
      "not": { "$ref": "#/definitions/name-a" }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! The solution worked when not wrapping the `not` in `{}`.

Comment: ha. oops. I'll edit and correct the mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Full (verbose) solution:

```
"files": {
  "not": {
    "items": {
      "not": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": { "enum": ["a"] }
        },
        "required": ["name"]
      },
      "not": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": { "enum": ["b"] }
        },
        "required": ["name"]
      },
      "not": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "name": { "enum": ["c"] }
        },
        "required": ["name"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```